# PowerApps Collect not pulling Choice column from list

Tags: canvas, powerapps

so i am trying to get a collection from a Choice column in a list, the column is also a multi select.  i have entered into the OnStart for the app the following code.

`ClearCollect(colEmailGroupNames,Choices('Personnel List'.'Email Group'))`

When i go to view->collections and look at colEmailGroupNames it is blank.  there should be about 7 different titles Example: Group 1, Group 2, etc....

is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command so it gets executed. Click the three dots near App and then **Run OnStart**

[image]

After that, the collection will be populated.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.